# My coin base showing usdt received and completed but the balance does not show the usdt. What can be the reason?

Tags: transactions, coinbase-api

Usdt were transferred from another account in to my coinbase wallet account. The transaction says receive complete but they are not seen in my balance. It's been 5 days. What can be the reason?
But bnb which were transferred are seen in the balance.

The reason behind not showing it in balance